# Get Information from Checkbox

Tags: javascript

Can i get value from checkbox.?

i have forum :

```
<a href="#">WSN</a>
  <ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="wsn/qabala.php" onchange="getline();"  onclick="boxclick(this,'qabala')" /> Qabala</li>
```

im need get `Value` into getline function..

```
var getd = document.getElementById('value').value; 
alert(getd);
```

i tested id but it wasnt work..

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="checkbox" id="value" value="wsn/qabala.php" onchange="getline();"  onclick="boxclick(this,'qabala')" /> Qabala</li>`

Comment: What's this? A game of spot-the-difference?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You just have to select the element correctly first.

Since it doesn't have an `id` attribute, you cannot get it by id until you give it one.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  value="wsn/qabala.php"
  id="value"
  onchange="getline();"
  onclick="boxclick(this,'qabala')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

var getd = document.getElementById('value').**checked**;

Comment: That will tell you if it is checked or not, it won't tell you what the value is. Since it doesn't have an id, that won't even do that, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set id on your checkbox like below

```
 <li><input type="checkbox"  id = "value" value="wsn/qabala.php" onchange="getline();"  onclick="boxclick(this,'qabala')" /> Qabala</li>
```

Then use the same code you used to get value. Try and get back.